# problem with insert command oledb excel c#

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

some headers' names have linebreaks on it

for example:

"assetspec.

attrib"

im trying to insert data into that worksheet but i get error every time

i try with "INSERT INTO [EXAMPLE$] ([assetspec#_attrib]) VALUES (@a)",

"INSERT INTO [EXAMPLE$] ([assetspec# attrib]) VALUES (@a)"

"INSERT INTO [EXAMPLE$] ([assetspec#\nattrib]) VALUES (@a)"

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException "The INSERT INTO statement caontains the following unknown field name: ''ASSETSPEC# ATTRID". Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again

When i use the /n or (char)10, the error is that the bracket statement is incorrect

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: can you mention which error you are getting

Comment: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException "The INSERT INTO statement caontains the following unknown field name: ''ASSETSPEC# ATTRID". Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again,

Comment: When i use the /n or (char)10, the error is that the bracket statement is incorrect